# AspNetSession layout renderer not working

Tags: asp.net, logging, nlog, asp.net-4.5

I am using NLog for logging in my asp.net 4.5 website. I have used NLog 4.0. Now I need to use session variables in my logs. So i tries to use AspNetSession layout renderer. This layout renderer is included in Nlog.Web. I have added this dll and also under the extensions tag in NLog config file. But it gives the following error:

> ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-session'

I have also added `NLog.extended` dll and also under the extensions tag in NLog config file. But it also didn't help.

Please let me know what should i do.

[image]

Comment: This is discussed at Github. (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/767) This was an issue in the auto-load feature (fixed in 4.0.1). Also the `<extensions>` won't work here due to the unneeded / incorrect `assemblyFile` attribute.

Comment: I just saw the issue you linked, I'm using asp net 5 and after installing the `NLog.Web` package I still get the `Layout renderer not for aspnet-user-identity` and the same happens for all other `aspnet-`s and the `iis-site-name` as well. I'm registering things programmatically, is there a special way to load `NLog.Web` to make it work do I have to register it somewhere else? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install **[NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web)** assembly from NuGet by using the following command.

```
Install-Package NLog.Web
```

Comment: As an aside, I had to upgrade my NLog packages(NLog, NLog.Config, NLog.Schema) to the latest version as well to get rid of any errors.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. Thanks!